# "nvidia-304-updates" vs "nvidia-304" (and similar)?

Tags: nvidia, release-management

What is the difference between these two modules? Whoever created them didn't seem to think of including a clear description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can research which Nvidia driver you need at: [Unix Drivers | NVIDIA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html)

If you click on the 304 link, you find information about the driver and the *Supported Products* tab lists the cards that need this driver. Find your card and you will know which driver you need.

If you look up the package names in *Software Center* or *Synaptic*, you will find the url to that same Nvidia page in the package description and you will see the driver version that the Ubuntu package is providing.

The difference between `nvidia-304` and `nvidia-304-updates` is the Nvidia version (and perhaps the version of Ubuntu patch of that number) that it points to.

In general, the updates package will point to the newest revision by Nvidia and the package without updates in the name will point to the previous stable version. The exact relationship, however, may vary by Ubuntu release.

For example, at the Nvidia driver page, you can see that 304.108 is called "the Latest Legacy GPU version". It was released August 8, 2013. A link to the archived drivers shows that the previous version was 304.88, released on April 2, 2013.

So, in 13.10, 304-updates currently refers to 304.108 and 304 currently refers to 304.88

In general, you will want the updates version since it will point to the newest driver. But exactly what you need depends on the exact model of your card since the newest features in the driver may not work with your card.

In addition to the Nvidia number, the Ubuntu developers patch the driver, so the actual binary version to install contains the Nvidia number followed by the Ubuntu version number.

In 13.04 and 12.04 both packages refer to 304.88, but to different Ubuntu-patched versions. For example, in 13.04, 304 is `304.88-0ubuntu1` and 304-updates is `304.88-0ubuntu2`. Information about the Ubuntu version can be found in [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/).

So you see that the actual binary file that the nvidia-304 and nvidia-304-updates packages will provide to your system will change over time. You can see this easily by viewing the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/restricted/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304_304.88-0ubuntu1/changelog). 304 now points to 88, before that to 84, before that 64, etc.

A little research or experimentation may be needed to determine which each driver you need and it may change over time. On my laptop with an older Nvidia card, as the version numbers changed I had to go from 304-updates to 304 because 304-updates began to point to a newer version of the driver that caused problems for my card.

A note based on comments:

These version numbers assume that you are using the versions of 304 and 304-updates provided by the standard Ubuntu repositories. It is possible to replace the standard repository for these packages with PPA's (Personal Package Archives). One commonly used PPA is [xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa), which provides bleeding edge versions of the drivers. Someone may choose to use this PPA if they need or want a version of the driver that is newer than the one offered by the Ubuntu release they are using.

Here's the important point for the meaning of the 304 and 304-update packages (and others) after a PPA like that has been installed: they no longer have the same meaning. If you install 304 from xorg-edgers, 304 will now point to the newest driver provided by xorg-edgers and the relationship built into the package name structure will no longer hold. Additional Drivers will still report the the package name as 304 (because the package name hasn't changed). Nvidia-settings will report the actual version of the binary that it sees, in this case a non-standard 108. It doesn't know (or care) that the binary came from a PPA, not the standard repository.

Comment: That is not the difference. I use `nvidia-304` driver and my NVIDIA Driver Version is 304.108. Look [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/y0t3n.png).

Comment: @radu-rdeanu Well, the essential point of the answer was that the difference is which version it points to. I did forget to mention that this may change. Unfortunately, I also looked up the numbers in the Software Center (thinking this is what a new user is most likely to use) and it gives the wrong info. I always appreciate suggestions for improvement and clarification.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu, that URL (http://i.stack.imgur.com/) is not self explanatory. Where did you dig it up, what does it mean and how trustworthy is it?

Comment: I looked in USC and I haven't saw that difference. See [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tPlDU.png) and [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dqVMq.png). So, I am still curious, as probably the OP is, which is the difference (if there is one). I appreciate your effort, but, sincerely, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Hey, what is imgur and what are those images?

Comment: @radu-rdeanu I can only say respectfully that I believe this is the correct answer. I haven't had a chance yet to look into why SC is showing incorrect info, but your new image confirmed my suspicion about your setup. You are not running the 304/update from the standard repository, but from the PPA Xedgers. So naturally your system shows different package information. The OP is asking about the standard packages.

Comment: @radu-rdeanu The standard 304 in 13.10 is `304.88-0ubuntu8`. When you installed xorg-edgers, 304 was made to point to `304.108-0ubuntu1~xedgers~saucy1`. The Additional Drivers and Nvidia settings only show 304 and 108 (your first image) because that is what they see, but the SC (your later image) package info shows the actual name of the package you installed: a patched 108, which on your system is pointed to by 304. Btw, on my system SC apt-cache are now showing the same info, so that may have been a momentary glitch.

Comment: @dan3 Those images are from my desktop.

Comment: So @RaduRădeanu, am I allowed to accept this answer or will you provide a competing one?

Comment: @chaskes I think you are confused because of different versions of  `nvidia-304`. Would you say that is the same thing if I use **`nvidia-304` version `304.108-0ubuntu1`** (which is the last version of `nvidia-304`) and if I use **`nvidia-304-updates` version `304.108-0ubuntu1`**? If yes, than there is no difference. If no, which is the difference? That's the question.

Comment: @dan3 Make as you wish... Personally I don't understand where is explained the difference between “nvidia-304-updates” and “nvidia-304” and I don't have an answer for this. But if you are happy with this answer, then you should accept it.

Comment: @dan3 I made the answer more clear (I hope) in response to the comments. Please accept if you feel it explains the difference to you.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu: I think "apt-cache policy packagename" might be a better way than posting images on imgur.

Comment: @dan3 Thanks for accepting. Hopefully everything is clear now.

Comment: Well, now I have 4 options: n-304, n-304-upd, with / without the edgers PPA. Some of these are not easily backportable from saucy to LTS (which is what I'm trying to do). Ubuntu is becoming crap, fast.

Comment: @dan3 We're here to help you have a good experience with Ubuntu, but we're also not supposed to turn the comments into a chat. ;) You prob don't need edgers. What video card do you have and what laptop model? If you have both intel and nvidia graphics, that's a whole different situation. You may need to ask a new question describing the specific problems you're facing.

Comment: Please, don't worry about my worries or encourage my chatting tendencies. There are several new bugs on LP. I'm surprised I am the first one to report them.